# Build Python 3.8.3 with pyenv on Fedora

Tags: fedora, python-3.8, pyenv

I'm trying to build Python 3.8.3 using `pyenv` on Fedora 32: `pyenv install 3.8.3`. The error I'm getting is:

```sh
ERROR: The Python ssl extension was not compiled. Missing the OpenSSL lib?

BUILD FAILED (Fedora 32 using python-build 1.2.21-1-g943015eb)
```

I want to point out however, that I don't have `sudo` permissions on the machine. I went through the [common build problems](https://github.com/pyenv/pyenv/wiki/Common-build-problems), but I'm unable to fix the issue I'm facing. In addition, the OpenSSL lib is installed on the machine, i.e., `which openssl` outputs `/usr/bin/openssl`.

Any pointers?

Comment: Just guessing, but do you have `openssl-devel` installed? Perhaps it is necessary?

Comment: I don't have it installed and I see that it's necessary in the build problems link, but I can't installed it without sudo permissions.

Comment: It looks like "dependency hell", but you could install the necessary dependencies to a location you have permission for ... and then update path environment variables and/or specify paths to build scripts, etc.

Comment: I would ask the system administrator to install the Fedora package `python3-3.8.3` that's available for Fedora 32.  However, I know not all organizations/sysadmins are agreeable/responsive enough.